# UIDatePicker setEnabled must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, notifications

I want some objects to become not enabled and transparent after clicking "Don't Allow" for notifications. However, I have an error as on the image below. How can I solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let savedFirstNotification = savedFirstNotification {
        firstDatePicker.date = savedFirstNotification
    }

    if let savedSecondNotification = savedSecondNotification {
        secondDatePicker.date = savedSecondNotification
    }

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Yep")
        } else {
            print("No")
            self.notEnable()
        }
    }
}

func notEnable() {
    firstDatePicker.isEnabled = false
    firstDatePicker.alpha = 0.5

    secondDatePicker.alpha = 0.5
    secondDatePicker.isEnabled = false

    scheludeMeal.alpha = 0.5
    scheludeMeal.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Any UI change must happen in the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `notEnable()` on the main thread:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.notEnable()
}
```

Comment: That whole function needs to be called from the main thread, since all code in it is modifying the UI. Simply dispatching the first statement in it to the main thread won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Toggling the `isEnabled` property of a `UIView` needs to be done from the main thread, since that's modifying the UI, which can only happen from the main thread. You need to dispatch the call to `notEnable` to the main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async`. The closure of `requestAuthorization` seems to be executed on a background thread, hence the error you see when trying to update the UI from inside that closure.

```
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        print("Yep")
    } else {
        print("No")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.notEnable()
        }
    }
}
```